# Django+Vue：static file not found

Tags: python-3.x, django, vue.js

When I use Django+Vue to build a web appliction, It occoured that the staic files always not found though I had placed all the files correctly.

the logs from server like this:

```
WARNING Not Found: /static/js/app.4c2224dc.js
WARNING Not Found: /static/css/app.a5d43e07.css
WARNING Not Found: /static/css/chunk-vendors.2ccfa1b8.css
WARNING Not Found: /static/js/chunk-vendors.c2488b8d.js
WARNING "GET /static/js/app.4c2224dc.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
WARNING "GET /static/css/app.a5d43e07.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
WARNING "GET /static/css/chunk-vendors.2ccfa1b8.css HTTP/1.1" 404 179
WARNING "GET /static/js/chunk-vendors.c2488b8d.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179
WARNING Not Found: /login
WARNING "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 179
WARNING Not Found: //performanceProject
WARNING "GET //performanceProject HTTP/1.1" 404 179
WARNING Not Found: /performanceProject
WARNING "GET /performanceProject HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Comment: The questions is poorly detailed and shown logs demonstrate that like almost any URL gives 404, not only static files. The self-answer lacks explanation. Why installing `whitenoise`, how is `Vue` related to whitenoise of whatever? Static files can be served without additional packages for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by https://www.cnpython.com/qa/1400788.

```
1、pip3 install whitenoise
2、modify settings.py add 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE, example below:


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Add WhiteNoise here
    ...
]


# when DEBUG=true
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist/static')
# ]

# when debug=False
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist/static')

# always need to be set ignore debug=False or True
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'



3、python3 manage.py collectstatic
4、python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:XXXX
```